# While loop stop main loop

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, thread-safety, godot4

i make loop, but it stop main loop. Help plz

```
extends Area2D


@onready var sprite = $Sprite
@onready var audio = $Audio
@onready var body = $Body
var rock = false


func disable_stone(player, stone_thread):
    stone_thread.start(await disable(player, stone_thread))

func disable(player, stone_thread):
    if !rock:
        print("super")
        rock = true
        await get_tree().create_timer(0.5).timeout
        body.colbox.disabled = true
        sprite.modulate.a8 = 100
        audio.play()
        await get_tree().create_timer(2).timeout
        while !(player in get_overlapping_areas()): pass
        body.colbox.disabled = false
        sprite.modulate.a8 = 255
        rock = false
    stone_thread.wait_to_finish()
```

I spawn thread. I dont know how fix that. I trying all thats i know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Summary of how signals and await work

Signals are dispatched on the main thread, and executed synchronously.

When you `await` as signal※, the method returns (and thus stops executing) an object that represents the position inside the code it was.

Then when the awaited signal is emitted, Godot will take that object, try to find the position in the code it came from, and executes from there... Again: synchronously.

In consequence, when you `await`, the execution of the code will end up resuming in the main thread.

By the way, you know some signals `signal` will pass some arguments, well, when you `await` a signal, it returns the value of the first argument passed.

※: yes, you `await` signals. When you call `create_timer`, you get an `SceneTreeTimer`, and then you `await` the `timeout` signal from it. You could `await` any other signal.

*I also see you `await` the `disable` method, which makes that method a co-routine... And you are giving the result to the `Thread`? I don't think that is what you meant.*

---

### The root of your issue

The crux of your problem seems to be this line:

```
while !(player in get_overlapping_areas()): pass
# REST OF YOUR CODE HERE
```

You are making a loop waiting for the `player` to no longer be overlapping the `Area2D`. Except the list from `get_overlapping_areas` is updated on the physics frame. And if the main thread is here in this loop, it will never get to execute the physics frame. Which makes this loop an infinite loop.

Thus what we will be trying to solve is how to wait for the `player` to no longer be overlapping the `Area2D`.

**And don't use a secondary `Thread`, nor a co-routine, for this.**

---

### Solution checking every physics frame

An orthodox approach to solve this problem would be to check in `_physics_frame` if the `player` is still being overlapped by the `Area2D`. *By the way, instead of checking `player in get_overlapping_areas()`, check `overlaps_area(player)`.*

Since you do not care about the check right away, we need a second `bool` flag (aside of `rock`). I'll call it `waiting_exit`, so you can do this:

```
func _physics_process(_delta:float) -> void:
    if waiting_exit and not overlaps_area(player):
        waiting_exit = false

        # REST OF YOUR CODE HERE
```

It might be worth noting that `get_overlapping_areas()` (and `overlaps_area`) might give you slightly outdated results (if I recall correctly, they are updated after `_physics_process`).

---

### Solution connecting a method to the `area_exited` signal

You have a signals for when an object is no longer overlapping the `Area2D`: `body_exited` (if the object is a physics body or similar), or `area_exited` (if the object is another area).

Since you are checking with `get_overlapping_areas`, I'm assuming that `player` is an `Area2D`, and thus you need `area_exited`.

So you could connect a method to the `area_exited` signal (see [Using signals](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/signals.html)), and in that method you place the second part of your code:

```
func _on_area_exited(area:Area2D) -> void:
    if waiting_exit and player == area:
        waiting_exit = false

        # REST OF YOUR CODE HERE
```

---

### Solution connecting an anonymous method to the `area_exited` signal

While I can't recommend this approach (too much effort), it is a solution to connect an anonymous method to the `area_exited` signal:

```
# Declare a continuation variable
# Initialize it with an empty callable, so we can reference it
var continuation := Callable()

# Set the continuation to an anonymous method
continuation = func(area:Area2D) -> void:
    # Make sure the area leaving is the player
    if area != player:
        return

    # REST OF YOUR CODE HERE

    # Safely disconnect
    if continuation.is_valid() and area_exited.is_connected(continuation):
       area_exited.disconnect(continuation)

       # Release the reference to this anonymous method
       continuation = Callable()

# Connect the signal to the continuation
area_exited.connect(continuation)
```

And yes, you could reuse the anonymous functions. However, at that point using a traditional named function (such as in the prior solution) is better.

---

### Solution awaiting the `area_exited` signal

It might be tempting to `await` the `area_exited` signal, so I'm going to mention it here. However, I can't recommend this either (not thread safe).

I believe would be like this:

```
while player != await area_exited:
    pass

# REST OF YOUR CODE HERE
```

The issue is that might not work correctly when using multi-threaded physics (as your code would not be constantly awaiting signals).

---

### Solution checking every physics frame (but with `await`)

And finally, if you are going to solve this with `await`, I would suggest to `await` the physics frame instead:

```
while overlaps_area(player):
    await get_tree().physics_frame

# REST OF YOUR CODE HERE
```

There should be no issues with this approach (edit: it might take an extra frame compared to having the signal always connected, but that is a non-issue in this case), and it is the minimal change from what you have.